infinite loop with LC-3 assignment
I need help with a LC-3 program for a school assignment.  We to write a short (about 15 lines) code in machine code that
i)starts at x3000
ii) initialize index to zero
iii) For each data value
a) add index to value
b) output the resulting sum as an ascii character
c) increment index
d)repeat for the next data until terminating value is reached
iv) halt the program
my assembly language code is
.ORIG x3000

; Data to process
DATA .FILL x0033 ; 'C' ASCII value
 .FILL x0053 ; 'S' ASCII value
 .FILL x0000 ; Terminating value

; Initialize variables
LEA R0, DATA ; Load address of data into R0
AND R1, R1, #0 ; Initialize index to zero

; Loop to process data
LOOP LDR R2, R0, #0 ; Load data value into R2
ADD R2, R2, R1 ; Add index to data value
OUT ; Output result as ASCII character
ADD R1, R1, #1 ; Increment index
BRnzp LOOP ; Repeat for next data value until terminating value is reached

HALT ; Halt the program

.END

I am getting an infinite loop which obviously does not print ascii value to screen.  What am I doing wrong?

What kind of loop do you think you have written there? Possible answers are while-loop, for-loop, do-while or infinite-loop.

Hint 1: BRnzp is an unconditional (i.e  always) branch.

Hint 2: if it was a conditional branch what in C or java would the condition be,  or what, would it be testing, if anything? What's the proper exit condition?

it is an infinite loop.  I'm guessing that it should be BRn (=0)

BRx or BRxx are conditional branches, but try to articulate the complete condition you want to test to decide loop exit vs. loop continue.  In other words, what = 0?  Just = 0 is insufficient to form a proper exit condition.

This is where I am lost.  Should it be BRnp loop, or BRz loop.  Or is there something I am missing?

Yes, you're missing an exit condition and the proper way to test it.  Can you state the exit condition if you write the whole loop in psedo code?  That whole loop shoul only be a few kines of pseudo code.

Sadly I can not.  I am lost.

AND R2, R2, #0 ; Clear the index register to 0
LD R3, DATA1    ; Load the address of the first data value into R3
LOOP    LDR R1, R3, #0  ; Load the current data value
ADD R1, R1, R2  ; Add index to the data value
BRz HALT        ; If the value is 0, halt the program
TRAP x21        ; Output the ASCII character
ADD R2, R2, #1  ; Increment index
ADD R3, R3, #1  ; Move to the next data value
BRnzp LOOP      ; Go back to the beginning of the loop
HALT    TRAP x25        ; Halt the program

BRz takes one explicit operand, yhe target addess, but is also looks at the z falg.  What instruction sets an interesting z flag.?  Hint: it is none of the adds.

Suggest to study strlen.  It has the kind of loop and exit condition you're looking for. You should study that in C or orher high level language before trying same in assembly.

Your basic loop looks like while ( condition ) do { somethings; }  where you fill in the condition and the somethings..
